# Checking for an existing record in Sqlite in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, where-clause

Hii guys

Im trying to check for an existing record in android before inserting a record. i get an exception and when i check the logcat it says its  a syntax error. need some Urget help with this guys

thanks

```
DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection(EnterDetails.this);
db = dbConnection.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT 1 FROM" + DbConnection.TABLE + " WHERE "+ DbConnection.C_MNUMBER + " = " +EditTextMobileNumber.getText().toString().trim(),null);
boolean flag = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
Toast.makeText(EnterDetails.this,"Record Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
"SELECT 1 FROM"
```

to

```
"SELECT 1 FROM "
```

Comment: @Roses: check the logcat syntax error. It will repeat exactly what you give it. Once you see this, the omitted space will be obvious. This will help you in future debugging.